# Emitting an Object Particle based on a rotating parent

Tags: particles

I am animating a baseball spinning and moving through space.  I am using an attached emitter to produce particles based on the "seams" object of the ball.

As the ball spins, the seams are in different places.   I want each emission to reflect the current orientation of the seams, and stay frozen in that rotation.

Currently, ticking the [x] Rotation box under Render matches the initial orientation, and each particle continues to rotate as the parent object does.  I want to freeze its orientation once emitted.

[image: Particles all rotate with the parent object]

Comment: Try to set Lifetime to 1 frame and enable "Died" option

Comment: Tried that, no change in behavior.  They all rotate even after "death".